# Search Query Logs Dataset

Tags: dataset

I am looking for datasets related to search engine query logs. The dataset can be eCommerce related searches (Searches users do on amazon, alibaba, google, bing, duckduckgo etc). Searches related to politics on any search engine.

Also, can anyone link me to the AOL search query logs. I know that they exists publicly but I can't find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't many datasets available online that also include the text of the query, since sharing personal queries may lead to personal information leakage. AOL's Dataset is also considered a [leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL_search_data_leak) or better not a very thoughtful move. However, you can get the AOL dataset [here](https://jeffhuang.com/search_query_logs.html) (try the backup mirror link) along with other datasets and information about them.